# Spring boot How to access Appconfig properties in test case

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, configuration

I am new to web services and spring boot.  I have written a service for which I am now writing a test case.

My application gets Soap request, parses the body and saves contents into database. 
My test case tests this service.

When I run the application and send a request from Postman, it runs alright. But when I call my service method from test case, I get nullpointer for JaxBcontext.

I have declared Jaxbcontext in my AppConfig.java (which is annotated with @Configuration and my jaxb is a bean with @Bean annotation) in my service, I have @autowire to use jaxbcontext.

I have pasted code snippets for clarity. Please advise me what I am doing wrongly here.

**My test case**

```
public class ReferralExchangeEndpointTest {

    ReferralExchangeEndpoint referralExchangeEndpoint = new ReferralExchangeEndpoint();

    JAXBContext jbcTest;

    Marshaller marshaller;

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller;

    public ReferralExchangeEndpointTest() throws JAXBException {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        jbcTest = JAXBContext.newInstance(
                "our app schema"); // this is working fine, I have replaced schema with this text for posting it in stack.
        ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
        marshaller = jbcTest.createMarshaller();
        unmarshaller = jbcTest.createUnmarshaller();
    }

    @Test
    public void send() throws Exception {

        File payload = new File("payload.xml");

        Object x = unmarshaller.unmarshal(payload);

        JAXBElement jbe = (JAXBElement) x;

        System.out.println(jbe.getName());

        Object test = jbe.getValue();

        SendRequestMessage sendRequestMessage = (SendRequestMessage) jbe.getValue();

        // Method in test.
        referralExchangeEndpoint.send(sendRequestMessage);

    }

}
```

**My service class**

```
    @Endpoint
public class ReferralExchangeEndpoint {
    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReferralExchangeEndpoint.class);

    @Autowired
    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    @Autowired
         .
         .
         .


private Form parseBody(String payLoadBody) {
        try {
            Unmarshaller um = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            return (Form) um.unmarshal(new StringReader(payLoadBody));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to extract the form from the payload body", e);
        }
    }
```

**My appconfig file**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public JAXBContext jaxbContext() throws JAXBException {

            return 
    JAXBContext.newInstance("packagename");

    }

    @Bean public MessagingService messagingService() {
        return new MessagingService();
    }
}
```

Thanks.
Kavitha.

Comment: Your setup isn't threadsafe. I'd suggest refactoring and setting this up with Spring oxm, https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/oxm.html. You probably haven't experienced any concurrency issues as I guess you're testing locally with 1 request.

Comment: Thanks Darren, But by using that, will I solve the issue of being able to instantiate my AppConfig attributes for my application to use? Or do I have to do something else to get it working?

Comment: Thanks Darren, I am going to read more on the OXM and use it in my end point implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Solved **

My test case now looks like this.

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class})`
public class ReferralExchangeEndpointTest {

```
@Autowired
ReferralExchangeEndpoint referralExchangeEndpoint;

@Autowired
private JAXBContext jaxbContext;

private Marshaller marshaller;
private Unmarshaller unmarshaller;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
}

@Test
public void send() throws Exception {

    File payload = new File("src/test/resources/payload.xml");
    JAXBElement jbe = (JAXBElement) unmarshaller.unmarshal(payload);
    SendRequestMessage sendRequestMessage = (SendRequestMessage) jbe.getValue();
    JAXBElement<SendResponseMessage> response = referralExchangeEndpoint.send(sendRequestMessage);

    //TODO add remaining assertions on response after confirming what should the service return for these attributes.
    assertEquals("SiteId wrong in response: ", "siteId", response.getValue().getSiteId());
}
```

}`